# Normal variables - adding and multiplying by constant

Tags: probability

$X\sim N(a,b)$, while $c$ is constant.

Is is true that then:

1. $X+c\sim N(a+c,b)$  ?
2. $cX\sim N(c\cdot a, b)$  ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(a,b)$. Let $c > 0$.

Then, $X+c \sim \mathcal{N}(a+c,b)$ and $cX \sim \mathcal{N}(ca,c^2 b)$.

Comment: It should be $c X \sim \mathcal{N}(c a, c^2 b)$.

Comment: My bad ! thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The first statement is true. The second statement is false.

We have that
$$
F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(t-a)^2}{2b} }\mathrm dt
$$
and
\begin{align*}
F_{X+c}(x)
&=P(X+c\le x)\\
&=P(X\le x-c)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{x-c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(t-a)^2}{2b} }\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(s-c-a)^2}{2b} }\mathrm d(s-c)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b\pi} } \; e^{ -\frac{(s-(a+c))^2}{2b} }\mathrm ds.
\end{align*}
Hence, $X+c\sim\mathcal N(a+c,b)$.

To see that the second statement is false, calculate the variance $\operatorname{Var}[cX]$.